# Autoformatting of *.vue files in VSCode not working

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am working on a Vue.js project in VSCode 1.58.2.

Everything works smoothly; however *.vue files are not autoformatted on save.

My .vscode/settings.json

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false,
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false,
  "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your settings.json you should have:

1. `[vue]: {"editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"}`
2. `"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html"` to tell vue how to format the `<template>`
3. Full config:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    }  
}
```

NOTE: **If you have multiple formatters for .vue files you'll have to specify which one to use otherwise format on save will not know which one to use and it will default to do nothing. This will select "Vetur" as the default.**

Answer (score 1):

After trying a while I could solve the problem. My modified
.vscode/settings.json:

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false,
  "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false,
  "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false,
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

extending @MiKr13's answer, if you are using Volar extension

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
  }
}
```